# How to make a pointer to a variable whose address is stored in a char array?

Tags: c, pointers, string-parsing

I have a program in which I have stored the address of the variable "var" in a char array by this:

```
int var = 10; //defined in somefile
sprintf(varAddress,"%p",&var)
```

So now `varAddress` stores the address of `var` (e.g. `"0x7fff22b823dc"`).

Is there any way I can use `varAddress` to create a pointer to the variable `var`?

Comment: How did `0x7fff22b823dc` become a string?

Comment: so, you mean `0x7fff22b823dc` is `&var`?

Comment: Yeah, 0x7fff22b823dc is &var.

Comment: You probably need [`strtoll`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtoll/), but what are you _actually_ trying to achieve here?

Comment: How did you get the address of the variable into the string? Elaborate on what you're *actually* trying to do; this is an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info) for sure.

Comment: How did you come to know that `"0x7fff22b823dc"` is the address of `var`?

Comment: Why do I get a strong suspicion you are playing around with serialization and came upon a problem?

Comment: *Yeah, `0x7fff22b823dc` is `&var`*  If you know that the address of `var` matches the string, you don't need to parse the string into an actual pointer value. This is not making any sense. What exactly are you really trying to do?

Comment: @AndrewHenle I guess "defined in somefile" means the code has no access to `var`, only to `varAddress`

Comment: @anatolyg: As one has to somehow get that string from that module (which has to be a function to convert to a string), one could much easier expose `var`, resp. `&var` either directly or via that function. As others wrote: it just does not make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the format of the string matches implementation-defined format supported by `%p` format conversion, you can parse the pointer as follows:

```
int var = 10;
// Writing the address into a string
char buf[100];
sprintf(buf, "%p", (void*)&var);
printf("Address string: %s\n", buf);
// Reading the address back
void *ptr;
sscanf(buf, "%p", &ptr);
int *vptr = ptr;
printf("Got address back: %p\n", (void*)vptr);
```

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/mr3Jjw)

Note that unless the value of the pointer came from this running process itself, any attempt at dereferencing this pointer would be undefined behavior. Moreover, the object whose pointer you retrieve from the string must still exist, and the type of the pointer must match the type of the object. All these constraints make it very hard to envision a use case in which reading a pointer from a string would serve any practical purpose.

Comment: "unless the value of the pointer came from this running process itself" too weak constraint. The object must still exit, too and have the same type as the dereferenced pointer..

Comment: @Olaf Thanks for the comment! You are right, this usage has very tight constraints, to the point of becoming rather impractical to use.

Comment: Definitively. That's why answering is pointless until OP clarifies.

Answer (score -1):

if in your implementation casting integers addresses to pointers is safe and you know that at the particular address you have something you can access (for example the hardware register):

```
void *getPointerFromString(const char *addr)
{
    return (void *)strtoull(addr, NULL, 16);
}

/* .........*/ 

char varAddress[] = "0x7fff22b823dc";
int *ptrv = getPointerFromString(varAddress);

*ptrv = 10;
```